# What is an easy to use non command line source control?

Tags: version-control

I'm new to source control, and need a windows based, non command line source control that is easy for a beginner to use. I will use it for coldfusion, if that helps... Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Start with this http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ at the bare minimum, move to GIT once you get comfortable with command line source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows, have a look at [**TortoiseSVN**](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

Or, if you are looking for a more advanced distributed version control system, have a look at [**TortoiseHg**](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), a Mercurial client with graphical user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Most SCMs are command line based but have GUI interfaces.  For Windows, SVN, Mercurial, Git and others have Tortoise GUIs that you can find by searching for Tortoise[SCM name] in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to use, non-command line and distributed? You named it: [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) :P

- we do have a community edition free for less than 15 users
- it is fully distributed (ala Git, HG, but totally graphical)
- integrated diff tools (xmerge, xdiff with refactor support)
- integrated code review

and many more...